# Access Denied on some PDFs in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, pdf

I have a problem with accessing some PDF files from a folder. Some of them can be copies, deleted, whatever, but other PDF files from the same folder cannot be opened or anything like that.When I right-click on them, a few PDFs show me only Adobe Acrobat 9, Open, Open with..., Send To. If I try and open it with notepad, it says "Access Denied". The permissions are okay and the folder is not shared or anything like that. I tried to use Unlock tool, but nothing. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try rebooting the machine?

Comment: yes, i tried that too. and the machine is not in Active Directory or anything like that :(

Answer (score 0):

It is a very good possibility the files are corrupt. Run CHKDSK /R on the hard drive containing those files and try again.